# TigerGraphException - Expect JSON, got Query String

Tags: tigergraph

When I try to run my code in Streamlit using TigerGraph, it gives me the following error:

('The request cannot be processed: expected a JSON payload, but a query string was given.\nPlease visit https://docs.tigergraph.com/tigergraph-server/current/api/built-in-endpoints#_authentication for more information.', 'REST-1101')

My code can be found at https://github.com/Tabaxi3000/WatchParty

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 0):

Does this happen when requesting a token using pyTigerGraph?

If so, an update for pyTigerGraph was released that fixes this problem. Try updating your pyTigerGraph install with `pip install -U pyTigerGraph`.